Jacobian matrix from numerical discrete Poincare map - MATLAB
I am new to nonlinear stability analysis, and my question is based on my minimal understanding of the domain.
I am using MATLAB to get the numerical solution of a coupled nonlinear differential equation
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{3(\cos(\phi))^2(\gamma \sin(\theta) + \phi - \beta \cos(\theta)\sin(\omega t)) -3((\sin(\phi))^2 -19)(\gamma \sin(\theta) + \phi - \beta \cos(\theta)\sin(\omega t)) + 36\phi \cos(\phi)}{\cos(2\phi) - 17)};$$
$$\frac{d\phi}{dt}=\frac{6(\cos(\phi)+3)^2(\gamma \sin(\theta) + 2\phi - \beta \cos(\theta)\sin(\omega t))}{(\cos(2\phi) - 17)}$$
where $\gamma=1$ and $\beta=10$ are constants. For simulation I have taken $\omega=10$. Fig. (2) of Ref.
I have defined $z(t) = (\theta(t), \phi(t))$
Using ode45 in MATLAB, I have numerically solved the above coupled nonlinear equations to get $z(t)$. The solutions are periodic with period $T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$, and using this information I sampled the solution at $t=t+kT$, where $k=1,2,3,\ldots$ This sampled solution gives the Poincare map $F(z_k)=z_{k+1}$ in discrete numerical form.
From this discrete Poincare map, I want to find the Jacobian $F:J=\frac{dF}{dz}$.
Can someone please help me how we can get the Jacobian from the numerical discrete Poincare map?
Ref.: “Nonlinear dynamics and bifurcations of a planar undulating magnetic microswimmer”
DOI:https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.107.054211

To find the Jacobian of the right-hand side of a discrete system numerically, one should use the least squares method. Where the discrete system comes from, whether it is a Poincaré map or something else, is unimportant. What is important is that we can calculate its right-hand side many times around the equilibrium point to form a linear system for the least squares method.
For example, if we wanted to find the Jacobian at $(0,0)$ of the right side of the system
$$
x_{n+1}=x_n+2y_n+x_ny_n,\qquad y_{n+1}=x_n-y_n+y_n^2,
$$
we could use the following MATLAB code
n=300;
xarray= randn(2,n)*0.01; %the coefficient needs to be adjusted for better results
yarray= [];
for i=1:n
    yarray= [yarray F(xarray(:,i))];
end
J= yarray*pinv(xarray)

function y=F(x)
    y= [x(1)+2*x(2)+x(1)*x(2);x(1)-x(2)+x(2)^2];
end


thanks for the reply. In your answer, you are using the explicit expressions (R.H.S) to calculate the Jacobian (as shown in the code). What I am looking for is to calculate Jacobian from numerical data (Poincare map).

@T S Singh The explicit expression is used in this example code only to generate data. It is not used in any way to calculate the Jacobian.

Sorry I missed that. Is the interpretation of the above program correct? xarray are the data points where the function is going to be evaluated (or say initial conditions), and F(xarray) is the function's values (or in my case the Poincare data set).

@T S Singh Yes, xarray is $x$, yarray is $y= F(x)$ (columnwise).

@T S Singh Note that if the equilibrium position $x_{eq}$ is non-zero or $F(x_{eq})\ne 0$, then data in xarray and yarray must be shifted, i.e. $x-x_{eq}$ instead of $x$ and $F(x)-F(x_{eq})$ instead of $F(x)$.

Thanks for the note @AVK
